# Stripe texts out of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to strip the `<img>` tags and it's contents out of my string that is returned from the database.

**Example string**

```
//I want to retrive dummy texts from my string.
var string = "<img src='test.jpg'/>dummy texts <img src='text.jpg'/> dummby text dummy texts";
```

I have tried

```
if (string.indexOf('<img') != -1) {
    var newString = $(string).filter(function() {
        return this.tagName != 'img';
    }).text();
}
```

However, my DB has crappy data and sometimes return

```
//There is no closure for image tag. 
var string = "<img src='test.jpg'/>dummy texts <img src='text.jpg'/> dummby text dummy texts";
```

and my code would strip the entire string.

The image tag positions vary.

How do I strip the `<img>` tags efficiently?

Comment: If possible, it would be better to strip these tags from the string in your server side code (php, .net or whatever you are using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also do it without appending first.

```
var str = "<img src='test.jpg'/>dummy texts <img src='text.jpg'/> dummby text dummy texts";
str = str.replace(/<img[^>]+>/g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. your codes work for me. plus simple with regex.

Comment: This is defeatable via `<<img >img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/be6be2d78e54f776ae254b08cfd13d70?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />`.

Comment: Yea it is, but it also sounds like he's in control of the data source

Answer (score 2):

```
var str  = "<img src='test.jpg'>dummy texts <img src='text.jpg'>",
    text = ​$('<div />').append(str).remove('img').text();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sL6sV/)

Comment: If you're returning `text()` you don't need to strip the images. This will strip all other HTML, as well.

Comment: thanks for the help. the append works but Brian's answer seems less codes for me. +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the correct answer is that you [don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/271475). You need to use a proper XML parser. Fortunately, your browser is one! You could try using jQuery's document fragments:

```
function stripImages(markup) {
  var fragment = $("<body></body>").html(markup);
  fragment.find("img").remove();
  return fragment.html();
}

var s = "<img src='test.jpg'/>dummy texts <img src='text.jpg'/> dummby text dummy texts"
stripImages(s);
```

This'll create a document fragment, let you strip the image tags, and then get the sanitized HTML back.

Comment: Thanks for all the edits you have done. Brian's codes create less codes with regex. +1 though.

Comment: If this is to secure images from being passed, see my comment on Brian's code. Regex is not a viable solution for securing content from having HTML injected.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is wrapping the string in a DOM Element, which you could create on the fly like:

```
var el = $('<div>');
el.html("<img src='test.jpg'>dummy texts <img src='text.jpg'> dummby text dummy texts");
el.find('img').remove();
console.log(el.html());
```

then simply search and remove specific elements (images or whatever)

Comment: Thanks for the help. your codes work but I would prefer not wrapping additional div ii my codes +1 though